# Is my battery really fully charged? Should I use the "pulse repair" button of my charger?

Tags: battery-charging, charger, lead-acid

I have a 12V lead-acid battery that is detected at 0.8V when I use a multimeter:

[image: battery]

[image: multimeter]

When I plug my charger it says "fully charged":

[image: charger]

- Should I use the "repair" button of my charger (I don't know what it does)?
- Is my battery dead?
- How can I charge it with the charger I have?

I have no knowledge about this kind of things.

Comment: Welcome to the site. As you'll see in the tour, this site is for questions on electronic design. Questions on the use of equipment is off-topic and this question is likely to be closed. Again, welcome.

Comment: As I found some other questions that seem similar I thought it could be the right place… Any idea where on the Web I could post my question?

Comment: With the greatest of respect, looking and seeing other users misuse the site isn't really the route forwards - it's the site rules and tour :-) I've no idea where else you can post it. But why not simply search for it on Google as others do, rather than throw the question onto someone else's lap, you've got an entire internet at your disposal. Look up your model, find the manual, look for the terms. This is just three photos and a few sentences that expects mountains of effort in reply. Good luck with it and I'll leave you to your research, as it's a Q&A site here and not a discussion forum.

Comment: I would trust the multimeter if you test it on  a AA battery and it reads something like 1.2-1.5V.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would defenetly look at the multimeter readout. It looks like the battery is dead. When the voltage on 12V battery falls <9V it get's permanently damaged.
You can attempt to charge the battery using bench PSU, with low current at the start, however the capacity will be signifficantly lower forever.
I used to repair those batteries with charging them on bench PSU, adding distilled water, charging, adding few drops of water, discharging, charging, water and so on. But this is probably not worth it.

Comment: Thanks! I'll probably buy a new one then…

Comment: For the end test, You could connect a normal 12V car lamp to it and see if it lights up